# based on the radius make the text center of the circle

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```html
 <span class="qs">Q{{i + 1}} <a href="#question-view"></a></span>
<div class="tooltipp text-center    bubble[ngStyle]="bubbleStyle(prof?.proficiencyBrightness, prof?.proficiencyRadius)">
</div>
```

I have few circles with  different radius as shown in the below picture and text is there in the centre of the circle. for medium and larger circles the text is in the centre but for smaller circles, it is not in the centre.

```js
  bubbleStyle(b, r) {
    return {
      'height': 15 + r/2 + 'px',
      'width': 15 + r/2 + 'px',
      'min-height': 28 + 'px',
      'min-width': 28 + 'px',
      'max-height': 65 + 'px',
      'max-width': 65 + 'px',
      'background-color': 'rgba(5, 117, 230,' + b/100 + ')',
      'transform': 'scale(' + b ? b/100 : 0.09 + ')',
      'position': 'relative',
      'top': 15 - 25*r/100 + 'px',
      // 'left' :3 + 'px'
    }
  }
```

```css
.question-number {
  top: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  /* display: flex; */
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -9px;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share the html code as well?

Comment: I have added HTML code @Manjuboyz

Comment: Can you check the html, it is incorrect! can you reproduce the issue in the fiddle?

Comment: I cant it consists of lots of angular code.

Answer (score 0):

Changes CSS Use `transform: translate`

```
.question-number {
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  /* display: flex; */
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

Comment: `.question-number` In your HTML not found this Class